# How can I prevent Aperture from rotating photos on export?

Tags: apple-aperture, image-manipulation, os-x

Maddeningly, when I export masters from Aperture 3.5.1 many (about half) of the photos are arbitrarily rotated to an orientation that they were neither taken at nor displayed at by Aperture itself. Is there a reason for this, and more importantly, a way of preventing it?

Comment: Use Lightroom instead. :-)

Comment: Actually, the reason I am exporting is to avoid storing my photos in a complex database like Aperture or LR. I'm moving to a simple directory of year/month folders.

Comment: @ChrisFonnesbeck - note that with Lightroom, you can store your photos in a year/month folder structure and still also benefit from the ability to sort on other meta-data and keywords.  There really isn't a downside.  Properly configured, it can even take care of moving the photos for you based on meta-data.  There really isn't a downside unless you consider ability to actually find stuff a down side.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: apparently exporting with the ITPC information included causes many photos to be rotated.